# Геркулесовая каша — это не дамоклов меч

Tags: этимология, фразеология

> История неразрывно связала некоторые имена и понятия: геростратова слава, пиррова победа…
>
> Вот шесть имен: Ахиллес, Геркулес, Дамокл, Прокруст, Сизиф, Эзоп. А вот восемь понятий: 1)труд, 2) язык, 3) каша, 4) кинжал, 5) ложе, 6) столбы, 7) пята, 8) меч. Какие из восьми понятий не связаны ни с одним из шести имен?
>
> - 4,6
> - 6,8
> - 3,8
> - **3,4**

[*(Источник)*](https://ustaliy.ru/snax_quiz/test-po-russkomu-yazyku/14/)

Ахиллесова пята, геркулесовая каша, дамоклов меч, прокрустово ложе, сизифов труд, эзопов язык. Правильный, по мнению составителей, ответ выделен. Видимо, для них *геркулесовая каша* с Древней Грецией не связана. Правы ли они? Почему столбы не относятся ни к одному из имен, но не включены в ответ? Может, я что-то пропустил?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, составители руководствовались историчностью, как и указали в задании. Не знаю наверняка, не интересовался историей кулинарии, но полагаю, что геркулесова каша корнями в античность не уходит.

А что Вам с Геркулесовыми столпами не понравилось?

Comment: А Геркулес -- персонаж исторический? Если да, то почему бы зерно геркулес, названное по его имени, не считать подходящим под критерий историчности составителей?

Comment: Возможно потому, что речь в вопросе не о зерне, а о его производном продукте, каше. К тому же видно, что почти все выражения стали крылатыми (только "столпы" мне не встречались, но мало ли), а вот крылатых фраз про геркулесову мне не встречалось. Про историчность Геркулеса слышал точно, что она не на пустом месте: царь такой был, но с героем мифов он имеет мало общего.

Comment: Для справки: «Сущ. геркулес образовалось лексико-семантическим способом словообразования на базе ла­тинского имени мифического силача и героя Геркулеса». (ЭСРЯ Т. 1 Вып. IV стр. 59)

Comment: Разумеется. Но этим словом подразумевается всё тот же персонаж как и Улисс/Одиссей, например.

Comment: Вопрос: какие из понятий не связаны... а не: какие из шести слов не образуют совместно с именами крылатых выражений. Вот это, по-моему, важно (пусть и немного педантично).

Comment: А если точнее, то вопрос: какие понятия не связала история. И это возвращает к моему ответу. Думаю, составитель, скорее всего, предполагал именно такую линию рассуждения.